# MongoDB text search behaves weird for "91n2y"

Tags: mongodb

I'm experiencing some pretty wired behaviour with the MongoDB text search feature that might be reproduced as follows: Create a new collection containing only

```
{ "tiles" : ["91n2n", "91n2y", "91n39", "91n3k"] }
```

and add an index with

```
db.test.createIndex({ tiles: "text" })
```

Now, this query produces one result as expected:

```
db.test.find({
  $text: {
    $search: "91n2n",
    $language: "none"
  }
})
```

as does searching for "91n39" and "91n3k". However, for some strange reason, which smells like a bug to me, MongoDB doesn't find "91n2y", although it clearly should.

I could reproduce this with MongoDB-3.0.4 and MongoDB-3.0.5 on OS X and MongoDB-2.6.5 on Linux with a pretty basic setup. Also, I'm seeing exactly the same behaviour with

```
{tiles: "91n2n 91n2y 91n39 91n3k"}
```

or if I change the order of the elements.

Is this a known bug or limitation, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Text search is meant for natural language, not for technical identifiers. Maybe the stemming rules get into your way. When you are only looking for exact matches with the array entries, you should use a regular index, not a text index.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm now using a plain index on the array, which works fine. Nonetheless, I still think the the behaviour outlined above is a bug, as I'm explicitly setting `$language: "none"`.